# Countdown timer do not want to stop in java

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am trying to creating countdown timer using java with Netbeans 8.1 IDE,, My problem is when the timer gets 00:00 it do not want to stop..I have trying to write timer.stop(); but it still not working...Maybe you can help me ..

this is my source code :

```
 ActionListener action;
    action = new ActionListener() {  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           seconds--;

            if(seconds==0){
                minutes--;
                seconds=60;

            }
            if(seconds==0 && minutes==0){
                timer.stop();
            }

            String min = minutes <= 9? "0"+minutes:minutes+"";
            String seg = seconds <= 9? "0"+seconds:seconds+"";

            txtRemaining.setText(min+":"+seg);
        }

    };  
    this.timer = new Timer(interval, action);  
   this.timer.start();
```

Comment: Please create and post a valid [mcve], a small *compilable* and *runnable* program that shows your problem for us.

Comment: Seconds **never** == 0 when the key if test is called since if it's 0 you set it to 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if(seconds==0 && minutes==0){
    timer.stop();
}
```

seconds can **never** == 0 here since just before this block of code you call:

```
if(seconds==0){
    minutes--;
    seconds=60;
}
```

and if seconds == 0, you set it immediately to 60.  The solution is to swap these two lines:

```
// call this **first**
if(seconds==0 && minutes==0){
    timer.stop();
}

// call this **second**
if(seconds == 0){
    minutes--;
    seconds = 60;
}
```